# Handle Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm learning about Django QuerySet

This is my view

```
def CompletedFormulary(request) :
# Fonction qui donne un récapitulatif des informations du formulaire par rapport au dernier formulaire créé.

    # Reprise de tous les éléments de la table child et parent ayant l'ID le plus élevé
    identity = Identity.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]

    identityAll = list(Identity.objects.all())
    context = {
        "identity" : identity,
        "identityAll" : identityAll,
    }

    return render(request, 'recapitulatif_identity.html',context)
```

And my recapitulatif_identity.html

```
<h2 align="center"> Votre formulaire a été validé </align> </h2>


{% block content %} 
Votre personne porte le numéro : {{ identity.id }} 

<h3> Récapitulatif des données enregistrées : </h3>

<li> Civilité : {{identity.title}}</li>
<li> Nom : {{identity.lastname}}</li>
<li> Prénom : {{identity.firstname}}</li>
<li> Sexe : {{identity.sex}}</li>
<li> Date de Naissance : {{identity.birthday}}</li>
<li> Ville de Naissance : {{identity.birthcity}}</li>
<li> Pays de Naissance : {{identity.birthcountry}}</li>
<li> Nationalité : {{identity.nationality}}</li>
<li> Profession : {{identity.job}}</li>
<li> Adresse : {{identity.adress}}</li>
<li> Ville : {{identity.city}}</li>
<li> Code Postal : {{identity.zip}}</li>
<li> Pays : {{identity.country}}</li>
<li> Email : {{identity.mail}}</li>
<li> Téléphone : {{identity.phone}}</li>

<br></br>

{{identityAll}}

{% endblock %} 

<br></br>

<form method='POST' action='/Identity/accueil'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Retour fiche identité" />
</form>

<form method='POST' action='/BirthCertificate/accueil'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Création d'un acte de naissance" />
</form>
```

The problem is about the display from Identity Fields. I would like to print each row per line, and if it's possible remove [`<Identity: ..... >`

I don't know How I can do that.

This is the result

[image: HTML page]

Comment: You have a list of objects, you need to iterate over them (also the `list()` is unnecessary)

Comment: @Sayse Are you talking about `<li> Civilité : {{identity.title}} </li>` etc ... ?

Comment: `identityAll = list(Identity.objects.all())` - Querysets are already iterable

Comment: Yes, but the first one is `identity = Identity.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]` Can I iterate over identity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to iterate through.

```
<ul>
{% for item in identityAll %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! Exactly what I want. First time I make this kind go things so I don't get totally the philosophy.

Comment: @Andromedae93 If that's exactly what you wanted,then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just make a cycle (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle))

```
{% for i in identityAll %}
<p>{{i.title}}</p>
<!-- Any other property you want to add... -->
{% endfor %}
```